# Angularjs- keeps data of nonexistent dom element (ngIf=false)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, forms, angular-ng-if, http-post

My form has different fields for each type:

```
<form>
    <select ng-model="message.type">
         <option>SMS</option>
         <option>Email</option>
    </select>

    <div ng-if="message.type=='sms'">
         <textarea ng-model="message.body"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="message.type=='email'">
         <input type="text" ng-model="message.subject" />
         <textarea ng-model="message.body" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

It works great BUT when the user selects email first, writes something in the subject field, then changes back to sms type, then when I send the message object in $http.post, it sends the object with subject child, even though the dom element was deleted.

How do I fix it? I want to send only the data that is linked to existing dom elements.

Thanks

Comment: A quick hack should be using the same name ie message.body than server side you send the type as well so you've got the way to do thing.

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine several solutions:

### Delete the inappropriate attribute

You can do this when the selected option change:

```js
$scope.deleteInappropriateAttribute = function () {
    if ($scope.message.type !== 'email') {
        delete $scope.message.subject;
    }
};
```

```html
<select ng-model="message.type" ng-change="deleteInappropriateAttribute()">
     <option>SMS</option>
     <option>Email</option>
</select>
```

It's even better to make this action just before you post the form, in order to not force the user to rewrite the `message.subject` if he's switching frequently between the different options.

### Associate a different variable to each part of the form

```
<form>
    <select ng-model="message.type">
         <option>SMS</option>
         <option>Email</option>
    </select>

    <div ng-if="message.type=='sms'">
         <textarea ng-model="message.global.body"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="message.type=='email'">
         <input type="text" ng-model="message.email.subject" />
         <textarea ng-model="message.global.body" class="ckeditor"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

And then, only post the appropriate variable:

```
$http.post(
    'myUrl.php',
    angular.extend(
        {},
        $scope.message.global,
        $scope.message[$scope.message.type]
    )
);
```

Comment: I thought about that but it gets complicated when you have many more fields where some of them are dynamic (I simplified the form for the sake of this post). **Is there any better way?**
I always assumed that ng-show is keeping the data, and ng-if deletes it.

Comment: It deletes the DOM and the local scope, yep, but here, `message` is defined in the scope of the `form`. I have propose another solution, have a look!